# Jquery accordion disable further clicks on slidedown

Tags: jquery, events, click, accordion

I am new to jquery and I have implemented an accordion which slidesdown depending on the "clicked" div and other div slidesup. However, once a div is slidedown I dont want any more click events to be fired on it.How do I achieve this?

I have many divs like the one below -

```
<div class=tutorial> 
<div class =trigger>
<h1 class = "head"><img src="image.png" alt="" class = "image">First accordion</h1>
</div>
<div class=content> </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.content').hide();
$('.trigger').click(function() {
$('.content').slideUp("fast");                                                                                   $('.trigger').not(this).children('.head').children('.image').attr('src','help_arrowUp.png')
$(this).siblings('.content').slideDown('normal');
$(this).children('.head').children('.image').attr('src', 'help_arrowDown.png');
});
});
```

Appreciate any help. Thank You.:)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.content').not(this).slideUp("fast");                                                                                        
$(this).slideDown('normal');
```

use it like this

Comment: what you have mentioned is similar to what I am doing currently. I want to disable any more click events on a div when it is already slid down i.e, the currently selected div on slidedown, must not respond to any more click events on the same current div.